# Get audio data with Spotify iOS SDK 2.0

Tags: ios, spotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

I need to stream music from iOS device to another device. In previous SDK there was SPSessionAudioDeliveryDelegate protocol which has been provided this functionality but it worked too slowly. Is there a way to get audio data with Spotify iOS SDK 2.0?

If there isn’t, will it be included later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently missing from the new SDK. Please file a feature request as described in the readme.